# SSL for a website in Kohana

Tags: ssl, kohana, kohana-3

I have a website in Kohana 3.0.7 and I have purchased SSL certificate. I have marked the success page to which pay pal transaction details are returned with https. After the database is updated, I added following code -

```
$this->request->redirect('business/fnc_manage');
```

But this page is loaded with https and not loaded properly on Google Chrome.

If I try as following, it gives me 500 error -

```
  header("Location:"+url::base()+"business/fnc_manage");
  exit();
```

How can I get rid of this ? Does this mean that I'll have to ensure that all the resources loaded should be served over https ?

If yes, then I might have to change all the paths. How can I do it for HTML helpers ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but I'd say changing the `base_url` in your ***bootstrap.php*** could help:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url' => 'https://yoururlhere.com',
    'index_file' => FALSE,
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'cache_dir' => APPPATH . 'cache',
    'errors' => TRUE,
    'profile' => Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION,
    'caching' => Kohana::$environment === Kohana::PRODUCTION,
));
```